# My question was asked yesterday, the system says today

Tags: support, time

See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251212/suspension-till-2027) question. I asked it yesterday. But

```
asked:today
viewed:956 times
active:today
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All relative timestamps are based on 24 hours. What was yesterday for you, is less than 24 hours ago still.

If you hover over a relative timestamp, the tooltip will show you the exact date and time, in UTC.

That's because the site is used by people from all over the world, and we cannot know when they've gone to bed or gotten up for a new day yet. It may well have been posted 'today' for someone, *somewhere* in the world.

For the first 24 hours, it'll be posted 'today', the next 24 hours 'yesterday'. This will be the correct relative date for half the people visiting!